# Twilio REST API phone masking

Tags: twilio

Could someone tell me, how to implement phone masking with rest api? Api reference doesn't have a word about phone masking. Support didn't help. Looks like they didn't even read my request, because their answer was just pointing to [ruby example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails).

Comment: The Ruby example you linked shows how to implement phone number masking using Ruby and Rails and the Twilio API.  That same tutorial is also available in C#, Node, Python, Java and PHP: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?filter-product=voice.  If those don't help, maybe explain why not and what you'd like to see instead and we can help you out.

Comment: Those examples use SDKs. Nodejs sdk doesn't work on react-native. So, a good option for me is to use REST API instead. The question is how to implement phone masking with [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest)

Comment: Gotchya.  So you're building a mobile app using react-native?  If thats the case I'd caution you against using the Twilio REST API directly from that app.  You would need to embed your Twilio credentials into that app and its pretty trivial to extract them from the binary.  Instead I'd build a server API that your app can call which then calls the Twilio API.

Comment: @DevinRader, thanks for the warning! i'll look into security. I use firebase anyway, so i'll have to find way to securely store keys. Despite that, do you know how to solve the the original question?

Comment: why don't you hit me up in email and we can hash out something that will work for you in your scenario.  devin at twilio dot com.

Comment: @DevinRader, sent

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea how can I make masked phone calls using react native app. Like Uber do? Please suggest if you have any idea about this.

Comment: @ArchanaSharma you can. Read Twilio docs, I dont' remember how exactly, it was a while ago :) Good luck!

Comment: Please check this if you can help me out:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885780/devicenotready-error-registration-failed-react-native-twilio-programmable-vo