# deviceNotReady error : "Registration failed" react-native-twilio-programmable-voice

Tags: android, react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I am working on react native application and want to integrate the Phone masking feature like Uber do. I have choosen Twilio Phone Masking for this. I have used [react-native-twilio-programmable-voice](https://ahttps://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice) package.

I have integrated this using this link::  https://medium.com/@edzh1/create-a-twilio-voip-calls-in-a-react-native-app-35a729a9613d

I have done server setup successfully, using php. But getting error deviceNotReady error : "Registration failed". I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

This is initial function I am calling here::

```
initTwilio = async () => {
    const token = await this.getAuthToken();
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        await this.getMicrophonePermission();
    }
    const success = await TwilioVoice.initWithToken(token);
    if (success.initialized) {
        TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
            this.setState({ twilioInited: true });
        });
        TwilioVoice.addEventListener('deviceNotReady', function (data) {
            console.log('data', data) // getting error here
        });
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') { //required for ios
            TwilioVoice.configureCallKit({
                appName: 'ReactNativeTwilioExampleApp',
            });
        }
    }
};

getAuthToken = () => {
    return fetch('https://myurl/accessToken.php', {
        method: 'get',
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

Please help, and suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Hi @Archana Sharma were you able to solve this ? i am getting the exact same error. 
err: "Registration failed" in deviceNotReady call back.

Comment: @Pruthvi, not yet.

Comment: Hi @Archana the issue if fixed for me. there was a problem with google services json file. i downloaded the right file and it started working. i am able to receive call or reject it programatically but not able to handle calls programatically for ios however i am getting calls for both platforms.